# How to initialize class member variable to Null

Tags: scala, binary-tree

Here's my code

```
class BinaryTreeNode[T <% Ordered[T]] (v: T) {
  var left
  var right
  val value = v
}
```

Now, how exactly should I initialize left and right so that I can set them later?

Comment: The more-idiomatic approach is to use Option types rather than null. See [OptionT > null | prose :: and :: conz](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/06/05/optiont-null/). An even MORE idiomatic approach is to use Option types in conjunction with no vars to produce a persistent data structure. (Full disclosure: [prose :: and :: conz](http://proseand.co.nz/) is my blog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple initialization to `null` can be done with:

```
var left: SomeType = _
```

Note that the type `SomeType` has to be provided.

Comment: Yep.  I just realized that too.  Thanks!